# calling javascript from ASP.NET when using ajax extention

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, visual-studio

Well I am using `Visual Studio 2010`,

If I am not using `Ajax` extention i.e. if I am not using `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` 
then it is simple task to call a `JavaScript` function from `C#` code behind event of any control using "`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`"

But what should be done if my `C#` code is behind a control inside UpdatePanel and we are using `ScriptManager` to use `Ajax`

?!! please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button's onclick event:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertJsTest", "alert('test!');", true);
```